# How do I alter an existing makefile for visual studio to create x32 builds?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'd like to compile the source for an existing app to produce an x32 .exe. I only have the makefile (produced by visual studio 2008).

Comment: interesting, I had no idea you could use VS to create makefiles. Could you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: It cannot do that.  VS6 was the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: the existing app was compiled for "All CPU", so it worked fine on the target machine anyway.

The target machine was a x32 instance on Amazon EC2, and of course anything compiled for "All CPU" will work nicely on both x32 and x64 operating systems.